# JSONParser error parsing data

Tags: android

So far i used JSONParser ( based on tutorials ) to send data to server database and receive json objects as Login succesfull and so far... But now a want to send a request to server, select data from database which are arrays and get it back. Because of my poor knowledge in http request and receive protocols i can't modify JSONParser class which i believe the problem lies. I think that my received data are arrays but JSONParser class handles it as an object.

Activity

```
package com.example.tranfer;

import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataInsert extends Activity{

    Button buttonresults , buttonmalakia;
    TextView abc;
    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.1.2:80/xxxxxx.php";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.data_insert);

        buttonresults = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonresults);
        buttonresults.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new TakeResults().execute();
            }

        });

    }

    class TakeResults extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

         public void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                Log.d("meg", "meg");

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(DataInsert.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Καταχωρώ τα στοιχεία...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();

            }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "GET", null);
            return json.toString();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            Log.d("mega", "mega");
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(DataInsert.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        }
}
}
```

JSONParser

```
package com.example.tranfer;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }


    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"));

            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }


    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"utf-8"));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
              if(params!=null){
                  String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params,"utf-8");
                 url += "?" + paramString;
              }
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.d("JSONParser", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            Log.d("JSONParser2", jObj.toString());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("wrong2", jObj.toString());
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

php script

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","enippeas","taramas" );
$database = "etruck1";
$ok = mysql_select_db($database, $con);
mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $con);

$sql = mysql_query( "SELECT startPoli1 , finalPoli1 FROM customer ");
    if($sql === FALSE) 
    { 
    die(mysql_error()); 
    }
    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
   $results[] = array(
        'startPoli1' => $row['startPoli1'],
        'finalPoli1' => $row['finalPoli1'],     
         );
        // echo $row['startPoli1'];          
        // echo $row['finalPoli1'];
    }
    echo json_encode($results );
    mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

LogCat

```
08-10 22:33:00.334: D/JSONParser(8117): [{"startPoli1":"\u0391\u03b8\u03ae\u03bd\u03b1","finalPoli1":"\u039d\u03b1\u03cd\u03c0\u03bb\u03b9\u03bf"},{"startPoli1":"\u0393\u03b1\u03bb\u03ac\u03c4\u03c3\u03b9","finalPoli1":"\u03a4\u03c1\u03af\u03ba\u03b1\u03bb\u03b1"},{"startPoli1":"\u03a6\u03b9\u03bb\u03bf\u03b8\u03ad\u03b7 \u03a8\u03c5\u03c7\u03b9\u03ba\u03cc","finalPoli1":"\u03a4\u03c1\u03af\u03c0\u03bf\u03bb\u03b7"},{"startPoli1":"\u039c\u03b1\u03c1\u03bf\u03cd\u03c3\u03b9","finalPoli1":"\u039a\u03b1\u03bb\u03b1\u03bc\u03ac\u03c4\u03b1"},{"startPoli1":"\u03a3\u03b1\u03c1\u03c9\u03bd\u03b9\u03ba\u03cc\u03c2","finalPoli1":"\u0391\u03bd\u03b4\u03c1\u03af\u03c4\u03c3\u03b1\u03b9\u03bd\u03b1 \u039a\u03c1\u03ad\u03c3\u03c4\u03b5\u03bd\u03b1"},{"startPoli1":"\u039c\u03b1\u03c1\u03bf\u03cd\u03c3\u03b9","finalPoli1":"\u0395\u03c1\u03bc\u03b9\u03bf\u03bd\u03af\u03b4\u03b1"},{"startPoli1":"\u039d\u03ad\u03b1 \u0399\u03c9\u03bd\u03af\u03b1","finalPoli1":"\u0394\u03bf\u03bc\u03bf\u03ba\u03cc\u03c2"},{"startPoli1":"\u0391\u03c7\u03b1\u03c1\u03bd\u03ad\u03c2","finalPoli1":"\u03a4\u03c1\u03af\u03ba\u03b1\u03bb\u03b1"},{"startPoli1":"","finalPoli1":""}]

08-10 22:33:00.825: E/JSON Parser(8117): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value [{"startPoli1":"Αθήνα","finalPoli1":"Ναύπλιο"},{"startPoli1":"Γαλάτσι","finalPoli1":"Τρίκαλα"},{"startPoli1":"Φιλοθέη Ψυχικό","finalPoli1":"Τρίπολη"},{"startPoli1":"Μαρούσι","finalPoli1":"Καλαμάτα"},{"startPoli1":"Σαρωνικός","finalPoli1":"Ανδρίτσαινα Κρέστενα"},{"startPoli1":"Μαρούσι","finalPoli1":"Ερμιονίδα"},{"startPoli1":"Νέα Ιωνία","finalPoli1":"Δομοκός"},{"startPoli1":"Αχαρνές","finalPoli1":"Τρίκαλα"},{"startPoli1":"","finalPoli1":""}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Note that the first line of LogCat indicates that arrays arrive correct to JsonParser...at least i believe so

Comment: The logcat error is clear: it expects a JSONObject and you send a JSON Array. Try to convert your data to an object before you send them

Comment: `type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject` couldn't really be any clearer. Don't parse it as an object, but rather, as an array: `jObj = new JSONArray(json);` -- need to change the return type of your method as well.

Comment: This JsonParser class serves also other activities which expect Jsonobjects. Do i need to create another similar class changing only JSONObject as JSONArray or is it possible to handle both situations whith the original JsonParser class;

Answer (score 0):

Since you are sending a JSONArray, you can modify this:

```
    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
```

To this:

```
    // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        try {
            jObj = new JSONArray(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

To attempt either case before throwing an error.

Comment: Can jobj be simultaneously JSONObject and JSONArray;